# Python: Running wget command results in it ignoring anything atter the hash in URL

Tags: python, escaping, wget

I'm calling the command here for wget for url **http://pypi.org/project/pip/#files**

```
    self.run_command('("wget http://pypi.org/project/pip/\#files -O index1.html")')
```

My log thinks that im running it without anything from hash onward

```
2020-01-27 11:37:23,128 020776:084 INFO:  wget http://pypi.org/project/pip/
```

Ive tried it without the quotes, brackets and escape characters but get same result. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: What are you trying to do, though? If you want to get information out of pypi, using [their API](https://pypi.org/help/#APIs) might be a smarter approach than trying to scrape their HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hash is interpreted as the comment char on the CLI and, therefore, everything after it is ignored.

In an URL the hash indicates an anchor to which the browser should scroll. In the URL definition in [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5) it is written, that the hash part (called fragment) is never transmitted to the server. I.e., you can savely drop it from the URL and just use:

```
self.run_command('("wget http://pypi.org/project/pip/ -O index1.html")')
```

Besides that: 1. Why not use the HTTP interface of python directly (instead of spawning processes)? 2. Why not use the PIP API directly?